# Bootstrap 4 fullscreen image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.ava-block {
  width: 220px;
  min-height: 155px;
  background: url(../images/no-banner.png) no-repeat;
  border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .ava-block {
      width: 100%;
      
      background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="ava-block" style="background-image: url(https://www.dean.ngo/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/projectElimu-220x155.png);">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
     </div>
```

I do `cover`, but image become with bad quality. How I can do it correctly? I need on tablets and mobile devices do fullscreen image, without quality loss and show full image. Width of image can be only `220px` and height `155px`.

Comment: you can't use a small image and hope it looks good when using `background-size:cover`

Comment: @DaFois what I can to do then ?

Comment: you must use a bigger image...

Comment: @DaFois but how then I can do image with size `220`x`155` ? I need only this size on page main.

Comment: you can project and use a different layout...

Comment: What size image (bigger) I need use for size 220x155?

Comment: @DaFois What size image (bigger) I need use for size 220x155?

Comment: I can't understand what you need, please add some screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the a small image to scale while maintaining image quality unless you make use of scalable image type such as vectors.

To solve the image going out of the ratio you could assign and max value for your inner block to ensure it doesn't exceed the maximum size which you had specified width:220 and height:155 or you can just make the size static. If my interpretation of the question is right, you may try something like the following:

```
  .ava-block {
  width: 220px;
  height: 155px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .ava-block {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="ava-block">
              <img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' src='https://www.dean.ngo/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/projectElimu-220x155.png' />

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```